# Solve an equation in mathematica without replacing the value of the parameter

Tags: equation-solving

Suppose I want to solve a simple equation in mathematica x-a=0.So I am writing the mathematica code for this as below:

```
Solve[x - a == 0, x]
```

So the output will be as below:

```
{{x -> a}}
```

Now suppose I have assigned a value for 'a' beforehand and then want to solve the same equation.So my code will look like below:

```
a = 1;
Solve[x - a == 0, x]
```

And the output in this case will be like below:

```
{{x -> 1}}
```

Now if I want an output in this case as `{{x -> a}}`,what modification should I do in my code ?

Note:  `Clear[a]` will work,but I don't want to remove permanently the assigned value to a

Comment: `Clear[a]` before solving?

Comment: Yeah it will work,but I don't want to remove the assigned value

Comment: What about `sol[a_] := Solve[x - a == 0, x][[1]]`

Comment: Depending on your use case, `a = 1; Block[{a = Defer[a]}, Solve[x - a == 0, x]]` might help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a better way for your solution but as far as I know:

You can use `Context` to manage variable scopes:

When you want to use a variable like `a`, Mathematica define it globally, what you can do is to do it in a context:

```
Begin["MyContext1`"];

a = 2;

Solve[x - a == 0, {x}]

End[];

(*Out: {{x -> 2}} *)
```

Now you want to use `a` again as a new variable without losing the previous value, use another context:

```
Begin["MyContext2`"];

Solve[x - a == 0, {x}]

End[];

(* {{x -> a}} *)
```

You can access the previous value by beginning the context you'd defined:

```
Begin["MyContext1`"];

a

End[];

(*Out: 2 *)
```

Remember if you use `a` without starting a context (use it globally), this solution will not work and also don't forget to end the context.

Comment: thanks @Beny Izd